# Extracting account's transactions with no other transactions with this counterparty

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a database with transactions of accounts. The relevant columns for me are: Account,Amount, Date, description and Transaction_Code. 
My goal is to extract rows for a given account which meets my trigger points.
The trigger points which I've succeeded writing are Amount greater than 200 and Transaction_Code in ('1,'2','3').
the only trigger point I'm struggling with is that: The account has no other transactions with this counterparty in the last 21 days. I've only succeeded in taking the range of dates I need.
Example for the Dataset:

```
**Account**    **Amount**      **Date**     **Description**      **Transaction_Code**
    555            280        2019-10-06        amt_fee                  1
    555            700        2019-09-20        refund                   2
    555            250        2019-10-01        amt_fee                  1
```

snippet of sql I wrote for the example for better understanding:

```
select Account, Amount, Date, Description
from MyTable 
where Account = '555' and Date between '2019-09-15' and '2019-10-06'
and Amount >= 200
and Transaction_Code in ('1','2','3')
```

The problem I have is how to do the condition of: ''The account has no other transactions with this counterparty in the last 21 days.'' Counterparty refers to the Description or Transaction_Code columns.
How should I do that condition for my true larger dataset? with groupby and count distinct?

Comment: `EXISTS` springs to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `not exists` condition with a correlated subquery that ensures that the same `Account` did not have a transaction with the same `Description` or `Transaction_Code` within the last 21 days.

```
select Account, Amount, Date, Description
from MyTable t
where 
    Account = '555' and Date between '2019-09-15' and '2019-10-06'
    and Amount >= 200
    and Transaction_Code in (1, 2, 3)
    and not exists (
        select 1
        from MyTable t1
        where 
            t1.Account = t.Account
            and (t1.Description = t.Description or t1.Transaction_Code = t.Transaction_Code)
            and t1.date < t.date
            and t1.date >= dateadd(day, -21, t.date)
    )
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and help, if my dataset consists of an inner join between 2 tables like that -   from myTable  a  inner join myTable2  b on a.Account = b.Account,  how can I name the join I did as a one table , and how to name it on the exists subquery?

Comment: @elads11: I answered the question that you have asked... If you have another question, then you would probably better ask a *new question*.